# Unpivot Multiple Columns in into Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I did some searching and didn't come up with a good answer. I am trying to create a table from data and then Unpivot it in SQL Server, but can't get the columns and rows required.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##EXPECT_PERCENTS') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE ##EXPECT_PERCENTS

CREATE TABLE ##EXPECT_PERCENTS (
   PAYOR_ID VARCHAR(40)
   ,TEST_TYPE VARCHAR(40)
   ,[2011-08-31] INT
   ,[2011-09-30] INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO ##EXPECT_PERCENTS VALUES('UHC','UDT','1','2');

select * from ##EXPECT_PERCENTS

SELECT PAYOR_ID, TEST_TYPE, EXPECT
FROM ##EXPECT_PERCENTS
UNPIVOT 
(
  EXPECT FOR EXPECTS IN ([2011-08-31],[2011-09-30])
) AS u
```

I am trying to unpivot the dates as well so that there is another field called "Date" with the two dates representing each number. The first line should be:

```
UHC UDT 1 2011-08-31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needing to unpivot multiple columns can often be easier without the `unpivot` command.  One option is to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select payor_id, test_type, expect, expectdate
from expect_percents
cross apply
(
  select [2011-08-31],'2011-08-31' union all
  select [2011-09-30],'2011-09-30'
) c (expect, expectdate);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bc610/7)

Another option is to use `UNION ALL`:

```
select payor_id, test_type, [2011-08-31] expect, '2011-08-31' date
from expect_percents
union all
select payor_id, test_type, [2011-09-30] expect, '2011-09-30' date
from expect_percents;
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bc610/4)

Comment: My personal favorite is to combine the CROSS APPLY approach with the VALUES clause... Like the answer to this one: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35620/is-there-a-better-option-than-union-all-for-multiple-selects-from-the-same-row

Comment: @EilertHjelmeseth -- nice addition to the solution!

Comment: The UNION ALL solution (without CROSS APPLY) will read the same row from expect_percents twice.